# afterFind() + paginate = errors in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, pagination

So I'm running a simple function in the afterFind of my model:

```
    public function afterFind($results) {
        foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['User']['password']) {
                $results[$key]['User']['status'] = 'active';
            } else if ($val['Ticket']['id']) {
                $results[$key]['User']['status'] = 'pending';
            } else {
                $results[$key]['User']['status'] = 'inactive';
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

It's giving me two errors, even though those variables are defined, and the page is rendering normally (apart from the errors):

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: User [APP/Model/User.php, line 145]

Notice (8): Undefined index: Ticket [APP/Model/User.php, line 147]
```

When I die() the unpaginated results, everything's fine... when I die() the paginated results, I still get those errors, even though all the data is identical.

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the keys are set. It is probably failing when pagination is doing `find('count`)` queries when the only value returned is the count.

A check like `isset($results[$key]['User']['password'])` should do the trick.